# Where is this text coming from with poltergeist?

Tags: ruby, capybara, poltergeist

I'm scraping my library's website with Poltergeist, in my first experience with that gem (or with Capybara, for that matter). It's working great. Super great.

```
def self.scrape_book_list(url)
    session = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist)
    session.visit(url)
    books = session.all('.js-titleCard')
    books_hash = books.map { |book|
      # getting info from the session
    } 
    books_hash
end
```

However, after the `session.visit(url)` line, before it even does anything else, it prints this:

> Hi there! This site is powered by OverDrive and our vision is a world enlightened by reading. Maybe a curious cat like you can help https://company.overdrive.com/company/careers/open-positions/

I've tried inspecting the page in Chrome, and even peeking at a few js sources, but I can't seem to figure out where this text is coming from!

I imagine the question is "Why/how is poltergeist doing this?" and I figured that searching the html or js code would turn the text up in some tag from the header that poltergeist perhaps always prints when it visits a page or something (maybe there's a different method to pass the url to besides `visit` that won't do this). But no luck!

I'm so curious (like the cat they mention)! Any ideas?

Comment: What URL did you visit?

Answer (score 1):

That text will be coming from a `console.log(...)` statement  somewhere in the sites JS.  By default Poltergeist outputs all JS console logs to stdout.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there's a way to suppress this?

Comment: @JonathanTuzman Setting the`:phantomjs_logger' option to an IO object should redirect it wherever you want - https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#customization